# How to generically traverse nested records looking for specific values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, generics

Assuming I have the following data types:

```haskell
data Person = Person
  { personName :: String
  , personAddress :: Maybe PersonAddress
  }

data PersonAddress = PersonAddress
  { personAddressStreet :: String
  , personAddressStreet1 :: Maybe String
  , personAddressStreet2 :: Maybe PersonAddressStreet2
  }

data PersonAddressStreet2 = PersonAddressStreet2
  { personAddress2StreetStreet :: Maybe String
  , personAddress2StreetNumber :: Maybe Int
  }
```

is there a way to walk a value of `Person` type in a generic way and report which specific fields have a value of `Nothing`?

Ideally I would like to see a full path of where in the nested structure that value was found (for example `(Person) personAddress -> (PersonAddress) personAddressStreet1`)

I looked at Typeable / Generic machinery and while it seems to be related to what I'm trying to do it isn't quite clear how I could utilise those here.

Any suggestions or pointers would be gladly received.

Comment: What do you think about lens ([for example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens))?

Comment: Tangential note: Why do you need address fields with `String` and `Maybe String` types? You would probably do better by settling on a single `Address` type with the appropriate fields and then parsing strings into addresses as necessary. Also, it feels strange to have an address type like `PersonSteetAddress2` in which all fields can be `Nothing` (except, perhaps, if you are using it to make sense of data extracted from some cranky database with ill-specified fields).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Generic` is the way to go for this. However, there are a couple ambiguities in your question still. I'll list these off, along with how I am assuming you want them addressed

- What is the type of a path in this case? I'm going to go with just `[String]` for now. Each `String` denotes either a constructor name or a field name.
- What happens if there is no field name? I'm going to record that as the field name `"no-field-name"`
- How deep should we go? For example, if you have a data constructor from another external module, should we search for `Nothing` fields there too? I'm going to make a type family which maps types to whether or not we should descend into the type.

---

As this solution is a bit long, I've separated bits of it with paragraphs. 
We'll start with a bunch of imports and pragmas and a class that contains our function `nothingFields`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, 
             MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeInType, FlexibleInstances,          
             TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables, UndecidableInstances 
  #-}
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

-- List of constructor or field names to descend to the right field
type Field = [String]

class NothingFields a where
  nothingFields :: a -> [Field]
```

Next, we will make a type family that maps types to a boolean saying whether or not we want to dig deeper into the type to look for `Nothing` fields. The catch all default case (the last one) is to stop digging.

```
 type family StopDigging a :: Bool where
   StopDigging Person = False
   StopDigging PersonAddress = False
   StopDigging PersonAddressStreet2 = False
   StopDigging [a] = StopDigging a
   StopDigging (Maybe a) = StopDigging a
   StopDigging a = True
```

Now, we want an instance of `NothingFields` and a helper class `NothingFields'` to branch on whether or not we have a type whose fields we should try to explore. Note this is a [well-documented problem and there are tricks to solve it](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap#Solution_1_.28using_safer_overlapping_instances.29).

```
-- This instance always matches because of its general instance head.
-- It dispatches to the right version of `nothingFields'` based on
-- whether  the `StopDigging` type family returns true or false.
instance (flag ~ StopDigging a, NothingFields' a flag) => NothingFields a where
  nothingFields = nothingFields' (Proxy :: Proxy flag)

-- Helper class whose instances' heads have different flags.
class NothingFields' a (flag :: Bool) where
  nothingFields' :: proxy flag -> a -> [Field]

-- Stop digging into fields
instance NothingFields' a True where
  nothingFields' _ _ = []

-- Continue digging into fields
instance (Generic a, GNothingFields' (Rep a)) => NothingFields' a False where
   nothingFields' _ = gNothingFields . from
```

The last instance is where the generic programming begins. As is habitual, we'll make a `GNothingFields'` class for this. Filling in the instances for this is pretty simple in most cases.

```
-- Generic helper class corresponding to `NothingFields'`
class GNothingFields' f where
  gNothingFields :: f a -> [Field]

-- constructors without arguments
instance GNothingFields' U1 where
  gNothingFields U1 = []

-- sum of constructors
instance (GNothingFields' f, GNothingFields' g) => GNothingFields' (f :+: g) where
  gNothingFields (L1 x) = gNothingFields x
  gNothingFields (R1 x) = gNothingFields x

-- product; multiple fields
instance (GNothingFields' f, GNothingFields' g) => GNothingFields' (f :*: g) where
  gNothingFields (x :*: y) = gNothingFields x ++ gNothingFields y
```

The remaining cases are: `M1` for metadata and `K1` for actual data in fields. Here is where the real tricks are going to happen. `M1` metadata is place around datatypes, constructors, and records. We want to keep track of only the last two:

```
-- The `D` tells us this is datatype metadata.
instance GNothingFields' f => GNothingFields' (M1 D t f) where
  gNothingFields (M1 x) = gNothingFields x

-- The `C` tells us this is constructor metadata, so we extract
-- the constructor name using `symbolVal`.
instance (KnownSymbol constructor, GNothingFields' f) => GNothingFields' (M1 C ('MetaCons constructor a b) f) where
  gNothingFields (M1 x) = (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy constructor) :) <$> gNothingFields x

-- The `S` tells us this is record field metadata, but the `Nothing`
-- tells us the field has no name.
instance (GNothingFields' f) => GNothingFields' (M1 S ('MetaSel ('Nothing) a b c) f) where
  gNothingFields (M1 x) = ("no field name" :) <$> gNothingFields x

-- The `S` tells us this is record field metadata, and the `Just`
-- tells us the field has a name, so we extract that using `symbolVal`.
instance (KnownSymbol selector, GNothingFields' f) => GNothingFields' (M1 S ('MetaSel ('Just selector) a b c) f) where
  gNothingFields (M1 x) = (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy selector) :) <$> gNothingFields x

-- This represents an actual data field of type `Maybe`. Note we
-- recurse using our initial `nothingFields` and not `gNothingFields`.
instance {-# OVERLAPPING  #-} (NothingFields a) => GNothingFields' (K1 i (Maybe a)) where
  gNothingFields (K1 Nothing) = [[]]
  gNothingFields (K1 (Just x)) = nothingFields x

-- This represents an actual data field of type _not_ `Maybe`. Note we
-- recurse using our initial `nothingFields` and not `gNothingFields`.
instance (NothingFields a) => GNothingFields' (K1 i a) where
  gNothingFields (K1 x) = nothingFields x
```

---

Now, to try this out:

```
ghci> nothingFields (Person "name" Nothing)
[["Person","personAddress"]] 
ghci> nothingFields (Person "name" (Just (PersonAddress "addr" Nothing Nothing)))
[["Person","personAddress","PersonAddress","personAddressStreet1"],
 ["Person","personAddress","PersonAddress","personAddressStreet2"]]
ghci> nothingFields (Person "name" (Just (PersonAddress "addr" (Just "street1") Nothing)))
[["Person","personAddress","PersonAddress","personAddressStreet2"]]
ghci> nothingFields (Person "name" (Just (PersonAddress "addr" Nothing (Just (PersonAddressStreet2 Nothing Nothing)))))
[["Person","personAddress","PersonAddress","personAddressStreet1"],
 ["Person","personAddress","PersonAddress","personAddressStreet2","PersonAddressStreet2","personAddress2StreetStreet"],     
 ["Person","personAddress","PersonAddress","personAddressStreet2","PersonAddressStreet2","personAddress2StreetNumber"]]
```

### Disclaimer

This was fun to implement but are you sure this is *really* what you want? Past being a debugging tool, I'm not sure this really has much utility... Anyways - enjoy!

Comment: Oh, wow, this is amazing :D I'm still digesting all the details but it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!